# execute code only when the "base" route is activated in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way to execute when a "base" route is activated/re-activated? I have the following urls:

```
Router.map(function() {

    // /projects
    this.resource('projects', function() {

        // /projects/2
        this.resource('project', {path: ':id'});
    });
});
```

I'd like to `transitionTo` the individual project route if there is only one project returned from the `projects` route. I can do this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('project');
    },

    afterModel: function(projects, transition) {
        if (projects && projects.get('length') === 1) {
            this.transitionTo('project', projects.get('firstObject'));
        }
    }
});
```

This works nicely...except i can still go to the `projects` route and since the model has already been loaded that hook doesn't fire again. Is there a way to listen to always enforce that rule when the `projects` route is activated?

For example, if i go to `/projects/23` and then i go to `/projects` i'd like to auto-transition them to the single project route if there is only one. I don't know how to accomplish that since it's a nested route and the `activate` and `afterModel` methods have already been fired when visiting `/projects/23` for the first time.

Does that make sense? and how can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an index route on your projects resource.  It will only get hit when you hit `/projects`

ProjectsIndex

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

    model: function() {
        var projects = this.modelFor('projects');
        if (projects && projects.get('length') === 1) {
            this.transitionTo('project', projects.get('firstObject'));
        }
    },

});
```